# Is there a function which generates gradient for any direction?

Tags: python, opencv

I have seen gradients which vary linearly. I want to apply the gradient to an edge so that the outer part of the edge is of one color and the inner part of the edge is of another color.

```
def linear_gradient(start_hex, finish_hex="#FFFFFF", n=10):
    ''' returns a gradient list of (n) colors between
      two hex colors. start_hex and finish_hex
      should be the full six-digit color string,
      inlcuding the number sign ("#FFFFFF") '''
    # Starting and ending colors in RGB form
    s = hex_to_RGB(start_hex)
    f = hex_to_RGB(finish_hex)
    # Initilize a list of the output colors with the starting color
    RGB_list = [s]
    # Calcuate a color at each evenly spaced value of t from 1 to n
    for t in range(1, n):
        # Interpolate RGB vector for color at the current value of t
        curr_vector = [
            int(s[j] + (float(t)/(n-1))*(f[j]-s[j]))
            for j in range(3)
        ]
        # Add it to our list of output colors
        RGB_list.append(curr_vector)

    return color_dict(RGB_list)
```

Comment: You are using `css` and `opencv` tag, right? Are aware of this? cuz I don't think anything can be relatable to `css` and `opencv`.  I believe you use css tag cuz you are working with color but there is a [tag:color] tag.

Comment: I have included css because I have seen some people using css for the same problem. But I am currently working on python.